# Laying out website div's with dynamic spacers

Tags: html

Here is a div layout :

```
<div id="mainContainer">
  <div id="leftSpacer"></div>
  <div id="Content"></div>
  <div id="rightSpacer"></div>
</div>
```

What I am trying to accomplish is set the mainContent a 1000px wide and of variable height based on content. The left and right spacers should resize themselves based on the display screen so that the mainContent does not move and the website appears centered on page. What is the best way to achieve this kind of dynamic re-sizing? The solution seeds to be browser agnostic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the flexbox,like this:

```
html,body{
  margin:0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
#mainContainer {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;

  -moz-box-orient: horizontal;
  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
  -moz-box-direction: row;
  -webkit-box-direction: row;
  -webkit-flex-flow: row nowrap;
  -ms-flex-flow: row nowrap;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
}
#rightSpacer,
#leftSpacer{
  background: red;
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -moz-box-flex: 1;
  -ms-flex: 1;
  -webkit-flex: 1;
  flex: 1;
}
#Content {
  width: 1000px;
  background: green;
}
```

but it doesn't support for ie9-. Pls view the [DEMO](http://codepen.io/airen/pen/lhwep)，if you want to know more flexbox, pls click [here](http://www.w3cplus.com/blog/tags/157.html).

Answer (score 0):

Apply below given style to your HTML and check that it full fills your requirement or not.

```
#mainContainer{
    width:100%;
    background:green;
    overflow:hidden
}
#Content{
    background:gray;   
    width:1000px;
    float:left;
    margin:0 auto; 

}
#leftSpacer{
    float:left;
    background:red;
}
#rightSpacer{
    float:left;
    background:red;
}
```